# R - how to re-order data frame by row index number

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, numbers, row

This may be a very basic question but I could't find it. Let's say I have a data frame `d` with row numbers in disorder like this:

```
    Signal
4   9998
3   549
1   18
5   2.342
2   0.043
```

How can I sort this by increasing row index numbers to obtain the following?

```
    Signal
1   18
2   0.043
3   549
4   9998
5   2.342
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
d <- read.table(text=readClipboard(), header=TRUE)    
d$index <- as.numeric(row.names(d))
d[order(d$index), ]
```

Comment: For some reason, the order of the rows ends up really weird: `1 10 100 1000 10000 10001 10002 10003... 10009 1001 10010 10011...`

Comment: Better to use `order`. There could easily be a rowname that is out of bounds. Also, rownames are characters, so they should use `as.numeric` first.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now with `as.numeric(row.names(d))` and order(). If @Paulo Cardoso edits his solution or if @Roland posts an answer I will pick either one as the chosen answer.

Comment: @Roland May I add your suggestion or you'll post it as an answer?

Comment: I just figured out you can edit other people's answers and edited Paulo's one; sorry for the confusion

Comment: @biohazard Thanks. is it working for you? that what matters =)

Answer (score 8):

you can also use this :

```
 d[order(as.numeric(rownames(d))),,drop=FALSE]
```

drop is useful only if your data.frame has one column otherwise remove it

Comment: May I suggest the use of `as.numeric()` as proposed by @Roland in the other answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
rownames(d) <- 1 : length(rownames(d))
```