# Read .txt-file reversed in R

Tags: r, reverse, read.table

I have a problem where I need to import a two column (first column being the x-axis and the second being the y-axis) .txt-file into R and I need to do this so that R reads it from bottom to top.

Here is what I did so far:

```
data<-read.table("data.txt",skip=1910,nrow=132982)

plot(data,type="l")
```

After this, I have the desired plot, but I wish this to be reversed horizontally. What would be the most convenient way to do this?

I tried

```
datar<-rev(data)
```

after import but it reversed the columns by switching the x-values to y-axis and y-values to x-axis. I wish to reverse the columns so that the last value in both columns will be the first in their columns without the columns switching places with each other.

I think that most convenient would be to revert the file during import as the file has over 130 000 rows and it is very cumbersome to work with.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See `order()` and sort your data after `read.table`. Also, avoid using `data` as a variable name...

Comment: This post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474030/r-how-to-re-order-data-frame-by-row-index-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be daft - but I don't see how order of reading x-y data would affect the position x and y coordinates.

maybe you want something like this:

```
data <- read.csv(text= "
x,y                  
1,1
2,2
3,4")
plot(data,xlim=c(3,1))
```

(x axis goes down from 3 left to 1 right)